# Why don't we wake up from thirst?

Tags: sleep

Usually, we sleep up to 7-10 hours. A healthy human drinks 2-3 cups per hour. Why don't we wake up from thirst if during the day, it is normal to drink so much?

I don't think that this is because you are paralysed during sleep. Your cells still need to stay alive, make ATP and proteins!

Comment: "*A healthy human drinks 2-3 cups per hour.*"  — That's between 7 and 12 litres per day. I don't think I myself drank more an 1L today. I guess I'm not very healthy then.  Why do you claim that people drink so much?

Comment: https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/how-much-water-should-you-drink#:~:text=If%20you're%20wondering%20how,if%20you're%20sweating%20heavily.

I searched it up.

Comment: That reference says "*Most people need about **four to six cups** of water each day.*"

Comment: @RayButterworth I think the confusion is from the fact that it says later in the same section that *"a general rule of thumb for healthy people is to drink two to three cups of water per hour, or more if you're sweating heavily."*

Comment: @EmmaGao Could you please incorporate that reference in your question? It makes it a better question, that can lead to you getting an answer sooner! The current comment thread would have been unnecessary. Whenever you have sources for your claims, please cite/link them! ;)